Resolving Peer Dependency Errors With Local Package in Node.js
I have a node service with several subservices in a project managed with yarn.  They all rely on one third-party library, but one of the subservices requires a later major release of the third-party library than the others.  This code works correctly and there are no conflicts when installing or running the code.
The earlier version of the library has a bug that won't be fixed by the maintainers of the library.  The application itself is too complex to update to move everything to the new major release.  In order to resolve this, I made a local package copy of the old version of the library with my simple bug fix. I have made no other changes to the library other than my bug fix.  I updated the package.json files in the application that rely on this library to use my local bugfixed package file and not to try to download a version from the Internet.  The use of the local package installs my code in node_modules and installs correctly.
When the application now runs, I get an error that two different versions of the library can not be used at the same time because unexpected or spurious behavior might occur.  I don't see a way to identify my patched local library with a version specifier in the dependencies in the main package.json files, but it's own package.json that describes the patched package has the correct version information.
I am not sure how to resolve this.  There are probably 100-200 package.json files in the application that specify a peerdependency of the library by version specifier. I think the same error occurs even without my bugfix, in other words, the same library downloaded from the Internet and retrieved by version specifier works, but loaded from a local file does not work.
**Works:**

Main - package.json  "somelibrary": "^10.x.x"
       Subsystem A - package.json  "somelibrary": "^10.x.x"
       Subsystem B - package.json  "somelibrary": "^11.x.x"

**Fails:**

Main - package.json  "somelibrary": "./localfolder/localsomelibrary"
       Subsystem A - package.json  "somelibrary": "../localfolder/localsomelibrary"
       Subsystem B - package.json  "somelibrary": "^11.x.x"

*My version of yarn does not require the "file:" prefix.

